# Center of a finitely generated fc group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

is the center of a finitely generated fc group (a group in which every conjugacy class is finite) also finitely generated?
And if yes, how can I prove it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All centralizers have finite index, so the intersection of the centralizers of a finite generating set, which is equal to the center, also has finite index and hence is finitely generated.

Comment: For a proof that subgroups of finite index in a finitely generated group are finitely generated, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13062/742).

Comment: Thank you both very much, i got it now!

Answer (score 4):

As [Derek Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820/derek-holt) notes in the comment, the center of a finitely generated FC-group is always of finite index in the group: the centralizer of any element is of finite index (the index equals the cardinality of the conjugacy class), and the center is the intersection of the centralizers of a generating set. The intersection of finitely many subgroups of finite index is itself of finite index, thus showing that $[G:Z(G)]\lt\infty$.

Now the result comes down to the following:

> If $G$ is finitely generated and $H$ is a subgroup of finite index, then $H$ is finitely generated.

There are three proofs of this result in [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13062/742).

(CW, since Prof Holt got there first, but hoping this will prevent the question from being "unanswered")